# Record writing in a .txt file is not working for sole .js fiile (running cmd: node fileName.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, file

I am writing a js code for record, insertion, deletion, etc. task. when I am writing the following function alone.. in another .js file, it is working.
`

```
const fs = require('fs')
let fInput = "You are reading the content from Tutorials Point"
fs.writeFile('tp.txt', fInput, (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   else{
      console.log("The file is updated with the given data")
   }
})
```

But on writing the this code the following way.. it is not working
I am not sure why is it happening.

```
// console.log('me');

const readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
const fs = require('fs');
// import * as readlineSync from 'readline-sync';
// import * as fs from 'fs';

function menu() {
    console.log("\n1: Insert a record");
    console.log("2: Update a record");
    console.log("3: Fetch a record");
    console.log("4: Delete a record");
    console.log("5: Display the data");
    console.log("6: Exit from the program");
}

function fileInit() {
    // file creation
    let output = "Name    Semester    Roll No.    DoB    CGPA    Contact No.\n"
    // fs.writeFile('students_details.txt', output, fileWritten);
    fs.writeFile('students_details.txt', output, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            console.log("The file is updated with the given data")
        }
    })
}


function main() {
    fileInit();
    var ch;
    do {
        menu();
        var ch = readlineSync.questionInt("\nEnter your choice: ", '6');
        switch (ch) {
            case 1:
                insertRecord();
                break;
            case 2:
                updateRecord();
                break;
            case 3:
                fetchRecord();
                break;
            case 4:
                deleteRecord();
                break;
            case 5:
                displayData();
                break;
            case 6:
                console.log("\nExiting from the program!");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("\nSeems there's some gabbad babe");
        }
    } while (ch != 6);

}


main();
```

I want a .txt file to be created with some initial given text init.
For example.. a "students_details.txt" file with the following result,

```
Name    Semester    Roll No.    DoB    CGPA    Contact No.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.writeFile` is asynchronous and may not finish before the next write to the file.

According to the documentation:

> It is unsafe to use `fs.writeFile()` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback.

Instead, consider using `fs.writeFileSync` in all your methods.

Comment: Oh! I see..
You are right, it is working now. Thanks!